# What does "Jazak Allah Khair" mean?

Tags: arabic, terminology

Asslamu allikum

I would like to know the usage of **Jazak Allah Khair**.
 When is it best used and, is there any restrictions?
*What does "Jazak Allah Khair" mean?
 When do we use "Jazak Allah Khair"?*

Jazak Allah Khair for the answers.

Comment: The correct pronunciation should be "Jazakallahu Khairan".

Answer (score 13):

- "Jaza" (جزا) is the Arabic verb meaning "May he give reward". The root is "Jazaun" means "reward". Although the meaning is such, literally, it's in past tense, meaning HE REWARDED. That's how a number of du'as are stated.
- "ka" (ك) here means "to/for you".

  So, "jazaka" (جزاك) means  "He will reward you"
- "Allah" here explicitly refers Allah as the doer (subject of the sentence or فاعل). Now "He" is "Allah".
- "Khair" (خير) is the noun meaning, "good".

The full meaning becomes: "Allah will reward you good". This is used as a Du'a by the Muslims and in Arabic it is: جزاك الله خيرا.

Comment: Be carfull here Jaza (جزا) is a generic verb in Arabic and it means judge and give the apropriate response 
so you may say " Jazak Allah Khair" (جزاك الله خيرا) may allah reward you
or if you want to ask Allah to exact punishment on someone you may say
" Jazak Allah Sharra" (جزاك الله شرا) may allah punish you 

and also Jazaa (جزاء) is the judgement and result

Answer (score 5):

It means **may Allah give you reward**.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the site! Generally, answers are expected to cite sources and be definitive. Please update your answer (if possible), it's currently flagged as low-quality. (See other answers to this question for the quality of responses the community likes.)

Answer (score 4):

عَنْ أُسَامَةَ بْنِ زَيْدٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏مَنْ صُنِعَ إِلَيْهِ مَعْرُوفٌ فَقَالَ لِفَاعِلِهِ جَزَاكَ اللَّهُ خَيْرًا فَقَدْ أَبْلَغَ فِي الثَّنَاءِ‏"‏

Usamah bin Zaid narrated that the Messenger of Allah (Peace be upon him) said:

"Whoever some good was done to him, and he says: jazaakAllahu Khayran ('May Allah reward you in goodness') then he has done the most that he can of praise."

Jami` at-Tirmidhi Vol. 4, Book 25, Hadith 2035

Comment: Even if this is a good quote, but evidences are not self-explanatory. Please consider editing your answer (use the edit link) and elaborate a good answer (read [answer])!

Answer (score 2):

**In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful**

---

Malik ibn A’yin quoted that I asked Imam Sadiq (a.s.):

… a Muslim tells another Muslim: جزاک الله خیرا  (Jazak Allah Khaira), what does it mean?

**Imam Sadiq (الامام الصادق) (a.s.) said:**

> (briefly translated): Khair is a creek in the paradise which is
>   originated from Kawthar-Nahr(creek), and at two sides of that
>   “Handmaidens (beautiful (women...) who are related to the paradise)” …
>
> In the meanwhile, it is remarked that it is related to the verse 70 or
>   Surah A’Rahman …

Afterwards, he said:

> Whenever a Muslim tells his (her) friend JazakAllah-Khaira, the
>   purpose of “Khair(Khaira)” is the homes (the places (or creeks) in the
>   paradise as it was mentioned before…)…
>
> معانى الاخبار شیخ صدوق ص 1

This expression might has worldly blessings/effects as well as its Okhrawi reward/effect (by surveying more explanations and interpretations, and so forth)

---

**Reference:**

- [chadorzahra.mihanblog.com](http://chadorzahra.mihanblog.com/post/157)

Answer (score 1):

***Jazākallāh or Jazāk Allāhu Khayran is a term used as an Islamic expression of gratitude meaning "May Allah reward you [with] goodness.***

Comment: Copy-Pasted answers are expected to be at least put in quotes along with the reference.

Answer (score 1):

AsSalamAlaykum,

The whole phrase "JazakAllah Khair" (جزاك الله خير) translated is “May Allah reward you with good”. It is used as a better alternative to thanking someone - you say a prayer for him/her. For details refer to [this article](https://littlemuslimhouse.com/what-is-jazakallahu-khair/).

Avoid using "JazaakAllah" alone because it is incomplete, because literally translated "Jaza" (جزا) more closely means "compensation" rather than "reward". It can also be used negatively for example in [verse 106 of Surah Al Kahf](https://quran.com/18/106).

So when thanking someone, use the complete term "JazakAllah Khair" (جزاك الله خير)