# How to perform Ghusal/Ghusl?

Tags: sharia, sunnah, ghusl

Assalammu allikum,

I would like to know the procedure for performing Ghusal/Ghusl (bathing).

[Jazak Allah Khair](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1891/337)

Comment: Salaam.It's a very typical question.Don't you think it's better to google for such these questions?

Comment: The answering style I see here is very different, with authenticated verses , then why dont we try making this a good collection of Q&A and hence helping others from a single window.

Comment: You've asked about the procedure(which you can find immediately through google). But if you're looking for any ghusl related verse or hadith you should ask your question more precisely.

Comment: Wasalam,Its ok friend.If you have the answer please post it down.I am waiting for others answers too Jazak Allah Khair

Comment: http://www.islamicinformation.net/2008/07/how-to-perform-ghusl-bath-in-islam.html

Comment: and a shia reference: http://www.theshiapedia.com/index.php?title=Ghusl#Tartibi

Answer (score 4):

Narrated `Aisha:

Whenever the Prophet took a bath after Janaba he started by washing his hands and then performed ablution like that for the prayer. After that he would put his fingers in water and move the roots of his hair with them, and then pour three handfuls of water over his head and then pour water all over his body.

حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ يُوسُفَ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا مَالِكٌ، عَنْ هِشَامٍ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، زَوْجِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم كَانَ إِذَا اغْتَسَلَ مِنَ الْجَنَابَةِ بَدَأَ فَغَسَلَ يَدَيْهِ، ثُمَّ يَتَوَضَّأُ كَمَا يَتَوَضَّأُ لِلصَّلاَةِ، ثُمَّ يُدْخِلُ أَصَابِعَهُ فِي الْمَاءِ، فَيُخَلِّلُ بِهَا أُصُولَ شَعَرِهِ ثُمَّ يَصُبُّ عَلَى رَأْسِهِ ثَلاَثَ غُرَفٍ بِيَدَيْهِ، ثُمَّ يُفِيضُ الْمَاءَ عَلَى جِلْدِهِ كُلِّهِ‏.‏

[Sahih Bukari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/5/1)