# Is it necessary to make wudu(ablution) after taking bath?

Tags: taharah

I took complete bath all over the body.

Now, Is it necessary to make wudu(ablution) after this?

Please, clarify me that if it is not necessary to make wudu, then how the bath should be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Take Bath/Ghusal?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/how-to-take-bath-ghusal)

Comment: Good question! While I know many friends who dress up and wear their socks immediately after bathing, and then do masah on their socks for wudu during the rest of the day stating that the act of bathing brings one into the state of wudu, I myself avoid doing this and make an explicit wudu after bathing and before wearing my socks. Touching the private parts breaks the wudu and I feel that this is inevitable during the act of wiping the body dry or while donning clothes.

Comment: Why does touching of the penis etc. break wudu?

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum, please refer to this website, I'm sure you'll be able to find what you're looking for. http://islamqa.info/en/5032

Answer (score 3):

The following is as per Ja`fari fiqh.

I am assuming when you say "bath", you are speaking about the ritual ghusl. There are three facets to this:

*After ghusl of Janabah, one must not do wuDu'.

*It is not necessary to do wuDu' after a wajib ghusl or a known mustaHabb ghusl. However, wuDu' is a precautionary recommendation after a known mustaHabb ghusl

*It will be necessary to do wuDu' after a ghusl whose istiHbab is not agreed upon.

397 A person who does Ghusl of Janabat should not do Wudhu for the prayers. In fact one can offer prayers without performing Wudhu after all Wajib Ghusls (except the bath for medium istihaza) as well as after Mustahab Ghusls (see rule no. 651). In the case of Mustahab Ghusls, however, it is better to do Wudhu as a recommended precaution.

[www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/ghusl.html#378) / Rule no. 651 is found here: [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/mustahabghusls.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assalumu alaikum
There are 4 fard acts when making wudu, and those are:
-washing of the arms to the elbow
-washing of the entire face
-masah of at least one quarter of the head
-washing of the feet to the ankle

As long as these four acts are complete, you are in a clean state ready for prayer. However, it is better to keep the habit of doing the sunnah as well, which includes everything else, even washing everything 3 times, as simply the intention of making wudu with sunnah is a great blessing In Sha Allah

"Say (O Muhammad): ‘if you (truly) love Allah, follow me! Allah will then love you and forgive your sins.’ And Allah is All Forgiving, All Merciful."} (Sura Al Imraan ayah #31) note: This ayah makes it very clear that if anyone claims to love Allah (swt) they have to follow the sunnah and only then will Allah (swt) love them and forgive them.  Many people today say we love Allah and they talk against the sunnah and the Ullima have said that anyone who does this is a liar and does not love Allah (swt) or they would follow the beloved prophet of Allah (SAW), as it is an order od Allah (swt) to do so.

http://dawaa.tripod.com/sunnah.html