# do I need to have Wudhu again if I just have a shower?

Tags: wudu

for instance, I just had a shower and I wanna pray after that.
do I have to do Wudhu after shower separately?
some references would be appritiated.

Comment: Have you looked into ghusl: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/how-to-perform-ghusal-ghusl

Comment: Do you mean showering or ghusl please specify! In any case I'd say this question would have an answer on the site you just need to search for it.