# What is the difference between Muslim , Mumin, and Muhsin?

Tags: practical-islam

[Asslamu allikum](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2146/337)

What is the difference between Muslim, Mumin, and Muhsin?

[Jazak Allah Khair](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1891/337)

Comment: not quite a duplicate, since it doesn't cover *muhsin*, but related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18/22

Comment: muhsin was the main part of it.Jazak Allah Khair for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are an Arabic reader you can check a detailed explanation for the [Hadith](http://www.islamweb.net/media/index.php?page=article&lang=A&id=58565) That was a conversation between the Prophet PBUH and a foreign Arab who came to ask about Islam, Iman, and Ihsan.

The difference between these three is the following:

- **Islam** is to certify that there is one God, pray 5 prayers per day, fast Ramadan, pay zakat, and go to Hajj for those who can.
- **Iman** is to certify the presence of God, his Angels, his Books, his Messengers, Doomsday, and Predestination (Good and bad ones).
- **Ihsan** is to Worship God as if you can see him, if you didn't see him, know that he does.

So as a summary the difference is that Islam is to be done with your actions, however Iman is more related to your heart and beliefs.

In the verse [49:14](http://quran.com/49/14) we can see the difference between Islam and Iman.

Ihsan is the most highest level among them. This verse [16:128](http://quran.com/16/128) shows how the Mohsin has a high grade from his God, because of the fidelity between a person and his God.