# When someone greets me with "salaam," is it more proper to respond "salaam," or should I respond "as-salamu alaykum"?

Tags: practical-islam, greetings, respect

I have some Muslim friends and they use different forms of greeting, so I am a little confused.

What would be a proper response to "salaam"?
When should I use the full "as-salamu alaikum"?
When should I reply with "wa-alaikum-salaam"?

Answer (score 1):

Saying:

> Salaam

is an incomplete greeting.

And Allah the almighty taught us how to respond:

> **And when you are greeted with a greeting, greet [in return] with one better than it or [at least] return it [in a like manner]**. Indeed, Allah is ever, over all things, an Accountant. ([4:86](http://quran.com/4/86))

so the minimum would be to return it (but that would be incomplete as gthe correct greetg is:

> As-Salamu 'Alaikum

, however it is certainly better to replay:

> (wa) Alaikum as-Salam
>   As-Salamu alaikum

and much better to say:

> (Wa) 'alaikum as-Salamu wa rahmatu-(A)Llah
>   As-Salamu 'alaikum wa rahmatu-(A)Llah

or

> (Wa) 'alaikum as-Salamu wa rahmatu-(A)Llah wa barakatuhu
>   As-Salamu 'alaikum wa rahmatu-(A)Llah wa barakatuhu

See also [How should I reply to "Assalamu Alaikum"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/how-should-i-reply-to-assalamu-alaikum) and [What is the meaning and the usage of "Assalamu alaikum"?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/what-is-the-meaning-and-the-usage-of-assalamu-alaikum?noredirect=1&lq=1)