# Ruling on cutting of nails after sunset?

Tags: sharia, taharah

Can I cut my nails after the sunset? Is there any ruling for this ?

[Jazak Allah Khair](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1891/337)

Comment: Why this question was down voted?

Comment: @tahirakram - Since in Islam halal is the default and haram is the exception, we discourage questions of the type "is x haram" *unless* the asker can demonstrate that there is some reason why they think it might be haram.

Comment: @SystemDown , In our places it is still belived that cutting of nails is not good after majrib.

Comment: @pckabeer - Then that should be mentioned in the question itself for the beniefit of people who don't have the same cultural background.

Comment: @SystemDown - Dear Freind , If I was a scholar , I wouldnt have asked this question here.And the cultural background , i dont think its that necessary.Use your time wisely , do good , avoid hatred :).Salam

Comment: @pckabeer - Oh I think its very necessary for this type of question. Or else we'll get flooded with "is x haram" questions for each and every silly little thing, made up or otherwise. See this meta discussion on this topic http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/355/the-useless-negative-problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no rule for this.

In old times, there was no electricity. Illuminating the environment and surroundings was a problem. Without sufficient ambient light, cutting nails, cutting hair, shaving, etc would spread around more dirt. One of the primary sources of what we call "dust" and "dirt" in our homes is nothing but hairs, granulated death skin tissues. So, in order to prevent or reduce undesired dirt at home. In worst case, this dirt may may even get into food and water in dark. People would had done these kind of sensitive body care works in the daylight. This stayed as a rule and reached to today.

If your house is lightened well, there is nothing to be afraid of cutting nails at night.

Answer (score 2):

There is  no rule for this. People are superstitious about cutting nails at  a particular time of day. There is no harm in cutting nails at any point of time. However, Prophet Mohammad (S.A.W) used to cut his nails on fridays. So a Muslim should try to cut his nails on fridays, but if he can't, then there is no harm in doing this on any other day. This is just a superstitious belief that we Muslims have gotten.

Comment: please add in hadith too