# Is it sunnah to eat dates before going to eid al-Fithr prayer?

Tags: sunnah, eid, reference-request

Asslamu alaikum,

Is it sunnah to eat dates before going for eid al-Fithr prayer? Any references for that?

[Jazak Allah Khair](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1891/337)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is :-)

It's sunnah to eat (in general) before going to Eid Al-Fitr prayer, and is sunnah to eat dates especially. And it's sunnah *not* to eat before going to Eid Al-Adha prayer, but rather eat after coming back from it.

For Eid Al-Fitr, here is a Hadith that confirms it is sunnah to eat dates before going to Eid Al-Fitr prayer:

> Narrated Anas bin Malik: Allah's Apostle never proceeded (for the
> prayer) on the Day of `Id-ul-Fitr unless he had eaten some dates. Anas
> also narrated: The Prophet used to eat odd number of dates.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الرَّحِيمِ، حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدُ بْنُ
> سُلَيْمَانَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا هُشَيْمٌ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا عُبَيْدُ
> اللَّهِ بْنُ أَبِي بَكْرِ بْنِ أَنَسٍ، عَنْ أَنَسٍ، قَالَ كَانَ
> رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم لاَ يَغْدُو يَوْمَ الْفِطْرِ حَتَّى
> يَأْكُلَ تَمَرَاتٍ‏.‏ وَقَالَ مُرَجَّى بْنُ رَجَاءٍ حَدَّثَنِي
> عُبَيْدُ اللَّهِ قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي أَنَسٌ عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه
> وسلم وَيَأْكُلُهُنَّ وِتْرًا‏.‏
>
> [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/13/5)

Hope that's helpful.