# Is it Sunnah to cut the nails?

Tags: sunnah, taharah

Is it Sunnah to cut the nails?

What is the way and the time or day that is best for cutting nails?

[Jazak Allah Khair](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1891/337)

Comment: Why do you keep linking all of your questions to your "jazak allah khair" question?

Comment: I would like to promote the usage of Jazak Allah Khair as much as I can :)

Comment: @pckabeer If it is, then you should promote the correct pronunciation. "Jazakallahu Khairan"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of scholars agree on this hadith:

> And he (may Allah have mercy on him) said in Sharh Saheeh Muslim
>   (3/149): It is mustahabb to start with the hands before the feet, and
>   to start with the forefinger of the right hand, then the middle
>   finger, then the ring finger, then the pinkie finger, then the thumbs,
>   then to move to the left hand and start with the pinkie finger then
>   the ring finger, until all the fingers are done, then to move to the
>   right foot and start with the smallest toe on the right foot and end
>   with the smallest toe on the left foot. And Allah knows best.

You can read the full fatwa [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/114810).

Comment: It perhaps is necessary to observe that the same source, *also* highlights that critics (such as Ibn Hajar, Fath al-Baari, 10/345) state that there is little evidence for most of that, and that much of it should be rejected.

Comment: It's a sahih hadith, i.e. gone through a lot of scrutiny.  So when others come along and say it should be rejected, such claims have little or no true value.

Comment: even if their criticism is fair and reasonable?

Comment: 1 or 2 minds compared to the scrutiny of the majority of highly islamically educated scholars?  I know who I would be voting for.

Comment: True, there is sometimes difference of opinion about whether a hadith is authentic or not. Regardless, if it's saheeh (and especially in Saheeh Muslim), there's no valid criticism against it -- it's already been scrutinized to death.

Comment: oshirowanen and @MarcGravell - note that the quotation is *not* of a hadith but from Imam an-Nawawi's *sharh* (explanation or exegesis) of Sahih Muslim. So you're both arguing about a moot point. And I actually agree that if you're quoting from that particular fatwa, it's more intellectually honest to cite both sides since the other opinion is not merely mentioned in passing in that link either.