# Missed Salat Al-Jumu'a unintentionally (while sleeping), what should I do?

Tags: jumuah, salat-qada

Assalamu 'alaikum wa rahmatu Allah wa barakatuh.

I've been working late at night and consequently I slept at morning, my friend told that he would wake me up when the time of salat Al-Jumu'a صلاة الجمعة comes, but he had to go before that and didn't wake me up, and so I was left asleep and missed the salat.

The story above tells that I missed the Jumu'a **unintentionally**, what should I do in this case? I just prayed Dhuhr, is there anything else/other I should do?

Answers with references are preferred, please.

[Jazakum Allah Khair in advance.](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1891/167)

Answer (score 7):

Assalamu 'alaikum brother,

> قال صلّى الله عليه و سلّم : " ليس في النوم تفريط . إنما التفريط على من لم يصل الصلاة حتى يجيء وقت الصلاة الأخرى . فمن فعل ذلك فليصلها حين ينتبه لها . فإذا كان الغد فليصلها عند وقتها". أخرجه مسلم).
>
> The Messenger of Allah, upon whom be peace, said, "There is no negligence in sleeping, but the negligence lies in not praying a prayer until the time of the next prayer has come. And whosoever does so should pray as soon as he becomes aware of the negligence." [Muslim]

If You missed salat Al Jumu'a unintentionally, just do salat duhr instead, And please pay more attention for it next time :)

More reading here about [missing salat al jumu'a because of sleeping](http://www.tunisia-sat.com/vb/showthread.php?t=1878171) [ARABIC].
This [fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/99471) for praying at al masjid (Mosque) in general [ENGLISH].

Allah knows better.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam O Aleikum,

So I've gone through this twice before, and today was just one of them. I started searching up online, even though it's not advised to, as it's not the most reliable source as I'm sure you are aware of.
What I did was, I got up, prayed Duhr, and just hoped of not getting any sins upon me, as I was not aware of my surrondings when asleep, and I had put an alarm on too. But then, I thought to myself, Allah didn't want to me pray this Jummah, and there is probably a reason, as Allah, thinks best for his servants, us. So, hopefully, InshaAllah, it's okay. But if you miss it three times unintentionally or intentionally, then you've got to straighten your acts up, and seek refuge from Him.
But, we can never be sure without any source.
Allah knows best.

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].